# Java Supplier<> defined as lambda. Need help understanding how this code even runs

Tags: java, lambda

Sorry for the somewhat unclear title but hopefully you'll see soon that it wasn't so easy to come up with a better one :)

So I have this interface that extends the Java Supplier @FunctionalInterface by defining one new method and also a default implementation of the Supplier.get() method. My default impl of .get() only wraps a call to the other method in some exception handling.

Then in my code I have different "versions" of this Supplier initialized using lambda notation.
Ex: `SomeSupplier s = () -> doSomething();`

Not sure why I even tried this because logically I don't understand how this even works, which it does. In my mind when I define my supplier using lambda like this I'm essentially overriding the Supplier.get() method. So how is it that in practice it seems to override my SomeSupplier.getSome() method? And leave the default impl of the .get() method intact?

What am I missing here?

---

Working example code:

````
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        SomeSupplier s = () -> getSomeOrException(); // "implements" the Supplier.get(), right?

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(s.get()); // => "Some!" or "null"
            Thread.sleep(2);
        }
    }

    private static String getSomeOrException() throws SomeCheckedException {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 10 == 0) {
            throw new SomeCheckedException("10 %!");
        }
        return "Some!";
    }

    private interface SomeSupplier extends Supplier<String> {

        @Override
        default String get() {
            try {
                return getSome();
            }
            catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        String getSome() throws SomeCheckedException; // How is this overridden/implemented?
    }

    private static class SomeCheckedException extends Exception {
        public SomeCheckedException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is that assuming that if a Lambda of a `Supplier` implements `get` then a lambda of a `SomeSupplier` must also implement `get`.

But instead a Lambda will always implement the single abstract method of an interface<sup>*</sup> it's about to implement. In `Supplier` that's `get`. Your `SomeSupplier` however has *implemented* `get` (with a `default` method). Therefore `getSome()` becomes the single abstract method of the functional interface `SomeSupplier`. So this line:

```
SomeSupplier s = () -> getSomeOrException();
```

is *roughly* analogous to this:

```
SomeSupplier s = new SomeSupplier() { 
    String getSome() throws SomeCheckedException() {
        return getSomeOrException();
    }
};
```

Note that this implements `getSome` and not the underlying `get` method.

*: This is also why functional interfaces can only ever have one abstract method: there's no fallback logic to pick one option if more than one such method exists for a given target type.

Comment: Thank you. I remember now that your "roughly analogous" code is how I stumbled upon this via the IDE suggesting to define it as a lambda instead. Cheers